# How to increment differently based on a variable

Tags: java, increment

What I need to achieve is to increase room numbers.
For example:

> 101, 102, 103 for floor = 1;
>    201, 202, 203 for floor = 2 ;
>   and so on.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: It is very hard to give a good answer based on such limited description. Please provide the code that is going to implement the solution.

Comment: It's just to create some Room instances with the room number increment like above and print out its variables. Nothing special

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have 5 floors and each floor has 3 rooms

```
for(int i=1; i<6; i++){
        System.out.println("The room numbers on floor " + i + " are: ");
        for(int j=1; j<4; j++){
            int room_num = i*100 + j;
            System.out.println(room_num);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a variable `difficulty` and you want to increment it on some event, so then in that event you write `difficulty++;`

If you meant you want it to increment every second, you do

```
while(true) {
    difficulty++;
    long ms = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Thread.sleep(1000 - ms % 1000);
}
```

If you want to make it so that when the room number is 100 or higher the level is 1, and when the room number is 200 or higher the level is 2 and so on... then you do

```
difficulty = difficulty - (difficulty % 100)
```